# How to create an instance of an object with a navigation property?

Tags: c#, object, properties

How to create an instance of an object with a navigation property?

In my application, I am using two classes to represent an object of Fruit and an object of Color as defined below.

```
public class Fruit  
{  
    public Fruit(int fruitId, string name, Color color)  
    {  
        FruitId = fruitId;  
        Name = name;  
        Color = color;  
    }  

    public int FruitId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public Color Color { get; set; }  
}  

public class Color  
{
    public Color(int colorId, string name, List<Fruit> fruits)  
    {  
        ColorId = colorId;  
        Name = name;  
        Fruits = fruits;  
    }  

    public int ColorId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public List<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }  
}
```

When creating an instance of Fruit or Color, I get their data from a database which is rather easy, but the problem is, I don't understand how to fill up the data for either the Fruit or the Color's navigation properties...

```
result = some_query_result_from_database...  
Fruit f = new Fruit(result["FruitId"], result["Name"], ???);
```

Problem:
If I replace the ??? from the above code with the following:

```
new Color(some_colorId, some_colorName, some_list_of_fruits)
```

Where can I get the **some_list_of_fruits**?

**Update #1:**

The Fruit and Color objects from above represents tables from a database, for this example I named it the same, so Fruit object has a Fruit table counterpart from the database and so does the Color object:

```
    Table definition:  
    +----------+  
    | Fruit    |  
    +----------+  
    | FruitId  |  
    | Name     |  
    | ColorId  |  
    +----------+  
         |∞
         |
         |1
    +----------+  
    | Color    |  
    +----------+  
    | ColorId  |  
    | Name     |  
    +----------+  

    Table contents:  

    Fruits  
    +---------+--------+----------+  
    | FruitId | Name   | ColorId  |  
    +---------+--------+----------+  
    | 10      | Apple  | 70       |  
    | 20      | Orange | 80       |  
    | 30      | Grapes | 90       |  
    +---------+--------+----------+  

    Colors  
    +----------+--------+  
    | ColorId  | Name   |  
    +----------+--------+  
    | 70       | Red    |  
    | 80       | Orange |  
    | 90       | Violet |  
    +----------+--------+
```

**Update #2:**

I overlooked at SriramSakthivel's comment, I realized SriramSakthivel is also asking how I get the data for my objects. So here it is.

For my Fruit object:

```
string cs = some_connection_string;  
MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(cs);  
try  
{  
    c.Open();  
    string query = select_statement_to_get_fruits_from_db;  
    ...then after that, I use MySqlDataReader to loop through the result to create fruit objects
}
```

For my Color object, it's just the same steps like the above commands except that on my query, I replaced it with a select statement to retrieve color data from database.

Comment: I can't see how this is answerable without understanding the context, if `Color` needs a list of all possible Fruits you would need to build that list before creating any Fruit() or pass in an empty list and add to it when all Fruit instances have been created.

Comment: That's a circular dependent constructor. Color needs a `List<Fruit>`, Fruit needs `Color` and that's never going to end. Much like a [Chicken-Egg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg). Without looking at DB schema and how you get data, we can't help much.

Comment: "Navigation properties"?

Comment: Are these Entity Framework entities?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was assuming the data will come from a database table that the Fruit or Color object is representing... That's why I wrote some_query_result_from_database above...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's exactly what my problems are..Because when I tried to instantiate an object of Fruit or Color, it's seems like there's no stopping creating more instances... And I don't know where to get those data... What should I do?...

Comment: @BenjaminPaul, well...the Fruit and Color object from above are a representation of a table from a database...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I have updated my post to show some db schema, will that be ok now?...

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework?  If so which version?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, no I'm not using Entity Framework... It's like EF but more like doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have circular dependency and you'll not be able to construct complete objects in constructor - you'll have to fill at least one side of circular dependency later.

One option is to build up collections of "fruits" while you are creating them:

- Build collection of all colors first but have lists of fruits empty (`Dictionary` by colorId is probably what you are looking for).
- When creating fruit register the fruit in Color's list of fruits:

Sample:

```
public Fruit(int fruitId, string name, Color color)  
{  
    FruitId = fruitId;  
    Name = name;  
    Color = color;  
    color.Fruits.Add(this);
}
```

You can also create colors on demand while creating fruit:

```
public Fruit CreateFruit(int fruitId, string fruitName, int colorId)
{
     if (!colorDictionary.ContainsKey(colorId))
     {
        var name = ...// Somehow get color name for colorID
        colorDictionary.Add(colorId, 
          new Color { ColorId = ColorId, Name = name, List = new List<Fruits>()});
     } 

     return new Fruit(fruitId, fruitName, colorDictionary[colorId];
}
```